# "Access is denied" error when starting the Web Management Service

Tags: windows, iis, group-policy, windows-server-2019, iis-10

I am trying to set up Web Deploy on an IIS 10 server running on Windows Server 2019. The **Web Management Service** must be running in order for this to occur, but it will not start.

I installed the Windows feature and can see the appropriate Windows service in service management. Unfortunately, when I try to start either through Service Manager or IIS's management tool, it fails. The Windows application event logs contain the following error:

> The Web Management Service service terminated with the following service-specific error: Access is denied.

[image]

And... that's it.

Here's my IIS Management Studio screen:
[image]

The closest I've been able to find to an answer is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/319197/iis-web-management-service-not-working-error-2147483640), which didn't help.

Comment: Check in `services.msc` if you can find the `Web Management Service`, what can you see there ?

Comment: @Swisstone Yes, it's listed as Manual start. When I try to start the service from there, I get the same problem.

Comment: Run Process Monitor, and then reproduce the issue. Then from Process Monitor log, locate any access denied log entries and check if they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Management Service will fail to start with a "Code 5" error in the console and an "Access Denied" event in the Windows security logs *if you have the **Block untrusted fonts** policy enabled*. This is a known issue that has been fixed as of build 1903.

Here's the Microsoft Tech Community post from a Microsoft support escalation engineer that solved this exact problem for me. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/wmsvc-web-management-service-failing-to-start-with-quot-access/ba-p/770603

It is likely that the **block untrusted fonts** setting is enabled on your server either by registry, local policy, or domain-based group policy. In my environment, I created a policy that only applies to Windows Server 2019 machines and disabled the following setting:

`Computer Settings > Administrative Templates > System > Mitigation Settings > Untrusted Font Blocking`

After running gpupdate and rebooting, the service started successfully.

Comment: For those concerned with the security implications, Microsoft (see link) feels that other protections in place justify disabling this setting. Also Duncan Clay in Sam's linked article includes a registry settings to grant an exception to wsman.exe if Group Policy is not an option or for testing. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/dropping-the-quot-untrusted-font-blocking-quot-setting/ba-p/701068